# Raw Query Convert VARCHAR to SQL Server Database Doesnt Work in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I try to do raw query in codeigniter to sql server database

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR," .$ColumnName. ", 120) LIKE '%".$_POST['search']['value']."%'");
```

`$_POST['search']['value']` is for search string input.

I tried to query using this string directly in navicat and it is working, however it didn't work when I apply it in codeigniter.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Firstly you must never use $_POST in a db query as this leaves you open to SQL injection. Massive no no :o) Second what is $ColumnName and why does it need converting to a varchar? Is query builder not a better option for you here?

Comment: Has @Antony said you should escape the variable first in your controller before you make the query, in codeigniter you can do it like this: $searchWord = html_escape($this->input->post('search')), and you should definitely use query builder here, see the docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data

Comment: I want to do a bug fix search date. For example in table the date is 2019-03-18. If i type 2019 all record appear, but in case i type 2019-0, data doesnt appear. Jquery ajax datatables is used.

Comment: If just query  in navicat using select*from tablename where columname like '%2019-0%' it giving zero record. If we change to like'%2019%' record will appear... I want to make dynamic search... If we convert to varchar first all record will appear

Answer (score 0):

In a model - the Query builder version would look something like this:

```
$db = $this->db;
$db->like($ColumnName,$_POST['search']['value']);
$data = $db->get(TableName)->result_array();
```

Codeigniter will escape the $_POST parameter making it safe. As long as $ColumnName is never passed in by the user as well :o) In that case it would need escaping too.